# How do I encrypt with javax.crypto.Cipher using my key?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I need a simple solution to the problem (I'm newbie). It consists in taking a certain 16 HEX key and encrypting another 16 HEX key with it. The algorithm requires 128 AES / ECB / NoPadding. It is in this format that the parameter of authorization of the device of the MiBand 2 fitness bracelet is perceived.
But all the solutions that I managed to find work by creating a key using "javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec".
I tried to send a key in the form of bytes to cipher.init, but I was told "argument mismatch; byte [] cannot be converted to java.security.Key", other formats also give an error. How can I come to a solution?

```
package com.company;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Main
{ public static void main(String[] argv) {
        String value = "9CC07199FECA0313403475ED62FEC727";
        System.out.println("encriptVal = " + encrypt(value) );
                                           }


    public static String encrypt(String value) {
        try {
            SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(hexStringToByteArray("30313233343536373839404142434445"), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks, cipher.getParameters());
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            return byteArrayToHexString(encrypted);
            }

        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                                               }

    private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String syc) {
        byte[] b = new byte[syc.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            int index = i * 2;
            int v = Integer.parseInt(syc.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
            b[i] = (byte) v;
                                           }
        return b;
                                                         }


    private static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] b) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(b.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            int v = b[i] & 0xff;
            if (v < 16) {
                sb.append('0');
            }
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(v));
                                           }
        return sb.toString().toUpperCase();
                                                         }


}
```

Comment: Your code is running like expected. The output is "encriptVal = E70D92ECB1B2038561BE298BF79C40D0A1C1EDE261B8F5F7D92A285F92765C2E" so I can't reproduce your question / error.

Comment: Yes, that is right. The fact is that the output will be 32 answers, and I need 16, as in my message with the key. I suspect that SecretKeySpec is doing some unnecessary transformations, which makes the encrypted response lengthen, so I want to run the code without this method to see if I'm right or wrong, but I can't run the code without the SecretKeySpec, and I ask how to ask key directly to cipher.init

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't follow you. Your key is a 32 (hex) character long string and after decoding it to a byte array you get a 16 byte long array, perfect for an AES-128 encryption. Your input is 32 character long = 32 bytes after encoding and your (hex string) output is 64 hex string characters = 32 bytes, so all is working as it should. But maybe your input is a **hex string** and should be encoded with "hexStringToByteArray" ??

Comment: I haven't learned to formulate yet. Therefore, I will try this way. I use an online converter, which, given the values of the message ("9CC07199FECA0313403475ED62FEC727") and the key ("30313233343536373839404142434445"), gives the result "797d862ea3fb6898d60f12f448d94d3c". I am trying to achieve the same through Java, but it gives me a result twice as long and with different characters. I tried to translate the key through "hexStringToByteArray" but I get a format error.

Comment: I recommended to run the **value** through the hexstringtobytearray converter...

Comment: But value.getBytes will convert it into bytes anyway

Comment: It's a big difference to convert via .getbytes or hexStringToByteArray...

Comment: Michael, thanks a lot for your tip! I spent 10 days trying to figure out these 50 lines. But now I roughly understood the java core (I watched the course in parallel), although I knew only a little AutoHotKey before. Thank you very much, you are the only one who responded. I got the desired encryption result.